# UIButton addTarget does not work in subclass of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

This is MyViewController.m

```
actionNames[0] = @"hoge";
actionNames[1] = @"piyo";

NSMutableArray *actionConts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
for(int i=0; i<[actionNames count]; i++){
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(DEVICE_WIDTH/3 * i, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH/3, 45)];
    // actionNames is NSMutableArray
    [btn setTitle:actionNames[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    actionConts[i] = btn;
}

// ↓ does not work
[actionConts[1] addTarget:self action:@selector(follow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// actionSubs is NSMutableArray 
for(int i=0; i<[actionConts count]/3; i++){
    actionSubs[i] = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, 45)];;
}
for(int i=0; i<[actionConts count]; i++){
    int sub = floor( (float)i / 3.0 );

    [actionSubs[sub] addSubview:actionConts[i]]; 

}

UIScrollView *actionScr = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 45)];
[actionScr setPagingEnabled:YES];
[actionScr setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[actionScr setBounces:NO];
actionScr.contentSize = CGSizeMake([actionSubs count] * DEVICE_WIDTH, 45);
for(int i=0; i<[actionSubs count]; i++){
    [actionScr addSubview:actionSubs[i]];
}
```

1. Create a button. => actionConts[n]
2. **addTarget** to actionConts[1]
3. actionSubs[] alloc
4. addSubView actionConts[n] to actionSubs[n]
5. addSubView actionSubs[n] to actionScr
6. (addSubView actionScr to drw)
   (drw is a UIView instance. "IBOutlet UIView *drw;")

When I click this button, It does not work... (´;ω;`)

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: It's because `[actionNames count]` is zero and hence your for loop never runs

Comment: actionNames is not actionConts so looking at the code you can guessing its empty

Comment: Could you please share the code that adds the buttons to superview?

Comment: What does actionConts[1] returns in the place where you marked as it doesn't worked? btw why do you assign buttons do the array with strings, a bit awkward

Comment: It returns a UIButton instance. actionConts[1].title == actionNames[1]

Comment: @sei0o hope, my answer below will be helpful

Comment: @AlexPeda sorry, it is still not working...

Comment: @sei0o there is a link to my xcode project with your code and it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine to me. I only replaced some lines:

```
[actionConts[1] addTarget:self action:@selector(follow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

replaced with:

```
for (UIButton *button in actionConts) {
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(follow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

that allows adding the actions to each button from array.

Also I replaced for-loop condition from:

```
for(int i=0; i<[actionConts count]/3; i++)
```

to:

```
for(int i=0; i<ceil((float)[actionConts count]/3.0); i++)
```

that allows having at least one superview for buttons.

Now `follow` is a method that will fire for each your button. You can set `UIButton.tag` property to clarify which one is pressed.